# How to limit Google Custom Search API query to specific websites/urls?

Tags: java, android, api, google-custom-search

I'm making an android app that uses the Google Custom Search API. But I need the query to only search/return results from specific websites/URLs.

How can I specify this?

Comment: i think this one link help you. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/annotations

Comment: @Hooman I have to do the same thing. Did you find the solution to do this thing programmatically?